# Core Data Query, most recent car per year?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my model I have a Car entity.

Car
 year
 createDate
 name

I want to run a fetch that returns all most recent cars per year where name is not nil (name can be nil).

So, if I have 3 cars with year 2000 and 5 cars with year 2010, I want to get a total of 2 cars out of the fetch request (the most recent for year 2000 and the most recent for year 2010).

I am not sure how to write the proper predicate to achieve this. I looked in the returnsDistinctResults option, but I am not sure that is the right path go go down and it also said that it only works with NSDictionaryResultType which does not work for me.

What would be the proper query/predicate to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off simply running over each record, with an algorithm.

Allowing for your Car class, define the following.

```
struct C {
    var year: Int
    var created: Date
    var name: String?
}

var cars = [C(year: 2009, created: Date(), name: nil), C(year: 2009, created: Date(), name: "Green"), C(year: 2010, created: Date(), name: "Green"), C(year: 2010, created: Date(), name: "Orange"), C(year: 2010, created: Date(), name: "Orange")]

var carsPerYear = [Int: [String: Int]]()

for car in cars {
    if let name = car.name {
        var info: [String: Int]? = nil
        if carsPerYear.keys.contains(car.year) {
            info = carsPerYear[car.year]
        } else {
            info  = [String: Int]()
        }
        if !info!.keys.contains(name) {
            info![name] = 0
        }
        info![name] = info![name]! + 1
        carsPerYear[car.year] = info
    }
}

for year in carsPerYear.keys {
    let info = carsPerYear[year]!
    let sorted = info.keys.sorted{ info[$0]! > info[$1]! }
    print(year, sorted.first!)
}
```

Gives output

```
2009 Green 
2010 Orange
```

Sometimes SQL or CoreData cannot solve the problems easily, it's best to just write sort algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this, if say you're passing an array of years into an algorithm, and expecting a result in the form of a dictionary, with each year you passed in as a key for an object that corresponds to the most recent car of that year.

ie:

```
let years : [Int] = [2000, 2005]


//The ideal method:

func mostRecentFor<T>(years: [Int]) -> [String:T]
```

Assuming you only use a small number of search years, and that your database has a small number of cars, you shouldn't have to worry about threading. Otherwise, for this approach you'd have to use concurrency, or a dedicated thread for the fetching to avoid blocking the main thread. For testing purposes you shouldn't need to.

To accomplish this, you would use a method that goes along the following line.

First, a number predicate should be used on the year like other answers have suggested. 
For this you would use the date format for NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", year)
```

Your model should, therefore, have the year as a parameter and the actual nsdate as another. You would then use a `fecthLimit` parameter set to 1, and a `sortDescriptor` applied to the nsDate key parameter. The combination of the later two will ensure that only the youngest or oldest value is returned for the given year.

```
func mostRecentFor(years: [Int]) -> [String:Car] {
        let result : [String:Car] = [:]
        for year in years {
           let request: NSFetchRequest<CarModel> = CarModel.fetchRequest()
           request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date == %@ AND name != nil", year)
           request.fetchLimit = 1
           let NSDateDescriptor: let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nsDate", ascending: true)
           let descriptors = [NSDateDescriptor]
           fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = descriptors
           do {
                let fetched = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as 
                [CarModel]
                guard !fetched.isEmpty, fetched.count == 1 else {
                    print("No Car For year: \(year)")
                    return
                }
                result["\(year)"] = new[0].resultingCarStruct //custom parameter here.. see bellow
            } catch let err {
                print("Error for Year: \(year), \(err.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return result
}
```

We use ascending set to `true` here, because we want the first value, the one actually returned due to the `fetchLimit` value of 1, to be the earliest car of the said year, or the one with the smallest timestamp for it's nsDate key.

This Should give you a simple fetch query for small datastores and testing. Also, creating a method or parameter to interpret CarModel into it's Car struct  counterpart could make it simpler to go from CD to your memory objects.

So you'd search for your cars like so:

```
let years = [1985, 1999, 2005]
let cars = mostRecentFor(years: years)

// cars = ["1985": Car<year: 1985, name: "Chevrolet", nsDate: "April 5th 1985">, "1999" : Car<year: 1999, name: "Toyota Corolla", nsDate: "February 5th 1999">]
// This examples suggests that no cars were found for 2005
```

Comment: I see what you mean, three problems with this: 1. This approach goes to disk a ton, very very slow. 2. This question is not asking to pass in an array of years, I simply want the most recent car for each year 3. This answer does not take into account the name != nil condition. Thanks.

Comment: 1: i specify that this approach is suitable for testing/small db's, and that you would need to adapt it to a concurency wrapper for anything more. 2: "each year" can mean anything from a collection of years, to every year between two given years which results in at the very least an array of years (or integers in this case).  3: indeed i forgot the name, checking for nil is done by adding an AND operator in the predicate string, and adding that avoided value either within the string or with the paramaeter notation. Ill update

Comment: This does not provide the answer the question is asking for. Sorry.

Comment: Your question is asking for the earliest cars of each year specified in the query which do not have a nil name no?

Comment: "Core Data Query", not "Core Data Queries". One Query to get what I want. What you provided goes to disk for every year I might pass in. Also, as I said above, I did not specify I wanted to pass in years. That is something you added here... So, again, sorry but your answer does not address the question. Thanks

Comment: I see. Indeed there is the IN operator, however i have yet to have use it with an AND operator practically. Won't be able to test it for an hour or so. However, thinking about it theoretically, if the AND IN combination works, to then get the earliest car of each year would still require a sorting method on the returned car array like the first Replier suggests; since using the fetchLimit approach i brought up would in that case only give you the earliest out of each year you want to query (fetchLimit set to 1), not each year's earliest car.

Comment: I think i have to concede with our colleague, i don't think a single query approach like you want is possible with your three conditions. It's close, but from my end the for loop (with or without a dedicated thread) does the trick of simplifying it down to only CD methods within a wrapper method, but again i think what you want isn't directly doable. I might be mistaken however, id look into the whole IN operator with an array of values like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538186/how-to-use-the-in-operator-with-a-predicate